# Setting user programmatically in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to log user programatically in ASP.NET MVC5. I'm setting auth cookies like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

I thouth it will be enough. But then I want to check value of Request.IsAuthenticated and it is always false. Also when I'm checking value of User.Identity.Name I'm getting empty string, not the username I passed earlier.

What should I do to make this work and set this values correctly?

EDIT:
One more thing. I'm not using any login form, I'm passing user data (login and token) from different application.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity?  If so, it doesn't use FormsAuthentication

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch why not

Comment: @meda - because it uses a different cookie based system

Comment: No, I'm not. Actually my approach is based on my old project written in MVC3

Comment: @PawełReszka did you enable form Athentication in your webconfig

Comment: @meda No, it wasn't. I enabled it and it works;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure form Athentication is enabled in your `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
...
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 12):

MVC5 comes with Identity instead of the older SimpleMembership and ASP.NET Membership. Identity doesn't use forms auth, hence why what you're doing has no effect.

To log a user in via Identity, first, you need an actual user instance, which you can get by doing something like:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(context); 
var user = userManager.FindByName(username);
```

Then if you have a valid user (`user != null`), you need to generate a claims identity for that user via:

```
var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Finally, you can use that identity to sign the user in:

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
```

(If you want a persistent login, change that to `true`)

Comment: It wasn't what I needed but thank you for your help;) It's my first project in MVC5 and i don't know best practices.

Comment: This was what I needed. In case you change the role of the current logged user it needs new cookies to be send. Otherwise the `User.IsInRole("RoleName")` wont work.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this part out for some time now.  Thank you for simplifing it to a point that I can understand how to use it.